# ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL when inserting value into Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

When I try to insert into my employee table I'm getting an error:

```
INSERT INTO employee (department_id) VALUES (1)
Error report -
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CYCLOPS"."EMPLOYEE"."ID")
```

Cyclops is my username that I've logged into the database as. I've created 2 tables. The employee table has a foreign key called `department_id` that refers to the `department` table `id` column.

```
Name          Null?    Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
ID            NOT NULL NUMBER(5) -- That's the primary key   
LAST_NAME              VARCHAR2(20) 
SALARY                 NUMBER       
DEPARTMENT_ID          NUMBER -- That's the foreign key to the department id column
```

This is my department table

```
Name            Null?    Type         
--------------- -------- ------------ 
ID              NOT NULL NUMBER       
DEPARTMENT_NAME          VARCHAR2(20)
```

This is a select all on my employee table:

```
id  last_name   salary
1   JONES       20000   
2   SMITH       35000   
3   KING        40000   
4   SIMPSON     52000   
5   ANDERSON    31000
```

This is a select all from the department table:

```
ID  department_name
1   IT
2   HR
3   SALES
```

What I want to do is insert the `department_id` into the employee record so I can add him to a department. Why am I getting an error on this insert?

Comment: Well, your INSERT statement doesn't provide a value for the `ID` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What I want to do is insert the department_id into the employee record so I can add him to a department. Why am I getting an error on this insert?*

You don't need to insert a new record, you need to update an existing record.

With `INSERT INTO employee (department_id) VALUES (1)` you create a new row where only the columns mentioned (in this case `department_id`) get values, all others are given `null`.

As your column `ID` is defined as `NOT NULL`, it throws an exception.

If you want to change your existing data, you need to `update` a record like

```
UPDATE employee SET department_id = 1 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE employee SET department_id = 2 WHERE id = 3;
```

Which will get you

```
id  last_name   salary   department_id
1   JONES       20000    1
2   SMITH       35000    (null)
3   KING        40000    2
4   SIMPSON     52000    (null)
5   ANDERSON    31000    (null)
```

Comment: OK thanks! That's very clear and that worked. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it says pretty clear what is happening.

The "employee" table has the ID non-nullable column

```
ID            NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
```

It means it's value can't be set to null

The command

```
INSERT INTO employee (department_id) VALUES (1)
```

will insert 1 to department_id and will try to populate every other column with null.

You need to provide id at least in order for making it work

```
INSERT INTO employee (id, department_id) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. The `id` column of the `employee` table is a primary key. So when I try to do the insert the way you'd said I get an error `INSERT INTO employee (id, department_id) VALUES (1, 1)
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (CYCLOPS.PK_EMP_ID) violated`